# Difference between star (verb) and starring

Tags: meaning

Definition from the dictionary:

> star - (of a movie, play, or other show) have (someone) as a principal performer.

Ok, sometimes I meet this word, used as follows:

> The movie stars Dustin Hoffman as an autistic man [link](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/STAR)

but much more often I face this word, used like this:

> A film starring Liza Minnelli

So what's the difference between this two words, when should I use each of them?

Comment: Does the dictionary you used for "star" not explain those other words?  If not then try a different dictionary.

Comment: *stars* is the 3rd person singular of the present tense of *star* and *starring* is the present participle. Wiktionary also says this about *starring*: *(with a film as its subject) That which has the specified actor or actors, especially those in lead roles, in its cast*.

Comment: @Archa how do you understand both these sentences? Is there difference for you?

Comment: It's the same word in different grammatical forms. An analogous situation exists with many verbs: "the store sells milk" vs "a store selling milk..." Note that the second form is not a complete sentence; there's no predicate. You might say e.g. *A film starring Liza Minnelli opened yesterday.*

Comment: 1. The movie shows Dustin Hoffman as an autistic man. 2. Liza Minnelli plays in a film as a principal performer.

Comment: @phoog "store sells/selling" example is a quite clear for me, I even could say that I can _feel_ small difference between these sentences, but "The movie stars Dustin Hoffman" sentences looks completely wrong for me, because it appears like movie is a subject and it plays (stars).

Comment: starring - (of a movie, play, or other show) having (someone) as a principal performer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between the words, in the sense that they aren't different words.   They are different *forms* of the same verb "to star".

The verb "to star" has both transitive and intransitive uses.   In either case, the verb expects a semantic *patient* or *theme* -- something that is affected by the action of the verb.   In the active voice, the transitive use displays this theme as a *direct object*.   The intransitive use displays its theme as a *subject*.

> This film stars Dustin Hoffman.   -- transitive 
>   Dustin Hoffman stars (in several films).   -- intransitive

Like any other verb, "to star" has several forms.   The -ing forms of this verb are no different than those of any other English verb.   "Starring" is the form used for gerunds and present participles.   Those are *non-finite* verb forms.   They do not create predicates.

> This film stars Dustin Hoffman. 
>   a film starring Dustin Hoffman

One major difference between these two examples is that **only the first is a complete sentence**.   The second is nothing more than a noun phrase.

Of course, that noun phrase can be used in a sentence:

> We watched a film starring Dustin Hoffman.

Answer (score 1):

They are actually different versions of the same word. "Stars" is the third-person present active indicative of the verb "to star." "Starring" is an present active participle of the same verb, and can often take a noun like the name of an actor when being used. Here are two example sentences using the verb "to star":

**Third-person present active indicative**

> The movie *The Martian* stars Matt Damon.

**Present active participle**

> *The Martian* starring Matt Damon

Answer (score 0):

I am in Africa and I was taught a verb represents an action. Something you can do or demonstrate. How do I do 'star'?. How do I demonstrate it? The fact that you had you add 'to' in front of your verb tells me that this is a fluid verb.